# Sort collection by another collection values

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, collections

I have `List<SomeData> data;`

```
public class SomeData
{
    public int Key { get; set;}
    public decimal Value { get; set;}
}
```

Also i have `List<int> DataOrder;`

I need to sort `List<SomeData>data` by `Key`, placing it in same order as `List<int> DataOrder` values.

Is there any common algorithms for that?

Example:

```
List<SomeData> data = new List<SomeData>();
data.Add(new SomeData{ Key = 10, Value = 14 })
data.Add(new SomeData{ Key = 25, Value = 22 })
data.Add(new SomeData{ Key = 567, Value = 3 })
data.Add(new SomeData{ Key = 57, Value = 300 })
data.Add(new SomeData{ Key = 17, Value = 200 })
data.Add(new SomeData{ Key = 343, Value = 42 })

List<int> DataOrder = new List<int>{1, 25, 700, 567, 343, 350, 10};
```

Result after sorting:

```
foreach(var element in data)
{
     Console.WriteLine(element.Key);
}
```

Out:

```
25
567
343
10
57
17
```

**Edit**: initial `data` array can have `Key`, that not contain in `DataOrder`
Such value should be placed at the end of result collection in any order.
Example changed to illustrate it.

Comment: can you show your sample data input and expected output?

Comment: what about size of DataOrder and Keys in SomeData, are they equal or may be any?

Comment: I added example of result i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about joining:

```
var mySortedList = (from i in DataOrder
            join d in data on i equals d.Key
            select new SomeData 
            { 
                Key = d.Key, 
                Value = d.Value 
            });
```

EDIT: To also add those values from `data` that do NOT share any key within the `DataOrder`-list you may simply add a `Union` to the result as follows:

```
var result = mySortedList.Union(data.Where(x => !DataOrder.Contains(x.Key)));
```

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Don't impose your indenting standards on others; not everyone indents the same way.

Comment: @HimBromBeere great solution, my solution likes your, but it's some difference

Answer (score 1):

### Solved

```
public class SomeData
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SomeData> orders = new List<SomeData>();

        orders.Add(new SomeData { Key = 10, Value = 14 });
        orders.Add(new SomeData { Key = 25, Value = 22 });
        orders.Add(new SomeData { Key = 567, Value = 3 });
        orders.Add(new SomeData { Key = 57, Value = 300 });
        orders.Add(new SomeData { Key = 17, Value = 200 });
        orders.Add(new SomeData { Key = 343, Value = 42 });

        List<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 25, 700, 567, 343, 350, 10 };

        //get orders only from ids with order
        List<SomeData> existedOrders = (from order in orders
                                        join id in ids
                                             on new { onlyId = order.Key }
                                            equals new { onlyId = id }
                                        orderby ids.IndexOf(id)
                                        select order).ToList();

        //add others
        existedOrders.AddRange(orders.Except(existedOrders).ToList());

    }
}
```

*//with @HimBromBeere solution you can reduce query*

```
//get orders only from ids with order
List<SomeData> existedOrders = (from order in orders
                                join id in ids
                                     on order.Key equals id
                                orderby ids.IndexOf(id)
                                select order).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for(int i in DataOrder)
{
    var index = data.IndexOf(d => d.Key == i);
    swap(data[count], data[index]);
    count++;
}
```

and swap function is for swap places of items.