# Angular: sort collection by list of values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, lodash

How to sort(Angular, Lodash) collection of objects according to specific order from other array:

```
var list = [{name: "Name 10"}, 
            {name: "Name 20"},
            {name: "Name 321"},
            {name: "Name 41"}];

var orderList = ["Name 20", "Name 41", "Name 321", "Name 10"];

//result: {name: "Name 20"}, {name: "Name 41"},{name: "Name 321"},{name: "Name 10"}]
```

I need apply order from `orderList` to `list`

Analog in c# [Sort collection by another collection values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672401/sort-collection-by-another-collection-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS support sorting by [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) filter. We need to pass expression function to filter as respect to other array. Check out below code:

HTML:

```
{{list|orderBy:order}}
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.list = [{name: "Name 1"}, 
        {name: "Name 2"},
        {name: "Name 3"},
        {name: "Name 4"}];
$scope.orderList = ["Name 2", "Name 1", "Name 3", "Name 4"];
$scope.order = function(predicate) {
    return $scope.orderList.indexOf(predicate.name);
  };
```

For better understanding i have made [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/uye2v3r8/)

Answer (score 1):

For this example we will render a list of friends using the `ng-repeat` directive. Using the built-in `filter` and `orderBy` filters we will filter and sort the friends list client-side.

```
 <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Filter">
 <ul ng-repeat="obj in list | filter:query | orderBy: 'name' ">
      <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: In that case I will get classic ordering but I need order according to `orderList`.